# InterstitialAd should load after every exposure

Tags: android, admob

I need to use InterstitialAd in my app. But the problem is that after first exposure, before showing I am creating ad, call loadAd method with request, and than show (calling show method)it in the right moment. Everything seems to work good, but when I try to call show method next time it doesn't work because of isLoaded returns false.
Is there any way to load ad only once.

**EDIT**

Thx for answer, but the main problem is that loadAd is network connection, but the google suggest not to perform internet tasks in main thread, so what the f..k it is loading ad from the internet in main ui thread.It causes lags in my app. They are contradicting themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to reload the ad anytime it's closed. I define a single method "reloadInterstitial()" and invoke it within the onCreate() method. It works great. All you have to do is call displayInterstitial() whenever you wish you to show the ad:

```
public class MyActivityClass extends Activity{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyActivityClass.this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("*****");
         reloadInterstitial();
        // Create ad request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

public void displayInterstitial(){  
        if(interstitial != null && interstitial.isLoaded())
            interstitial.show();
    }

private void reloadInterstitial(){
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyActivityClass.this);
                    interstitial.setAdUnitId("*****");
                    // Begin loading your interstitial
                    interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    loadInterCallBacks();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdOpened();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdClosed();
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyActivityClass.this);
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("****");
                loadInterCallBacks();
                // Begin loading your interstitial
                interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdLeftApplication();
            }
        });

    }


 private void loadInterCallBacks(){
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyActivityClass.this);
                    interstitial.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxx");
                    // Begin loading your interstitial
                    interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    loadInterCallBacks();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdOpened();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdClosed();
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyActivityClass.this);
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("xxxxxx");
                loadInterCallBacks();
                // Begin loading your interstitial
                interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdLeftApplication();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but the main problem is that loadAd is network connection, but the google suggest not to perform internet tasks in main thread, so what the f..k it is loading ad from the internet in main ui thread.It causes lags in my app. They are contradicting themselves..

Comment: What the f...k they try to tell you is to use a background thread to do the networky stuff...